# Selenium Download Keep and Discard Problem (.cer or xml extensions)

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, chromedriver, debugging

I'm `Test Automation Engineer`, working with `Selenium` and `Java`. I'm developing `selenium automation tests`, but I have a problem with downloading something from the software I'm working on.

`Chrome` asks me the security question in order to download `Keep or Discard`, but in `selenium`, as you know I cant click the `Chrome` window.

So I did try a few methods to get rid of this problem in `Chrome`, but I couldn't find a solution and this is important for me to continue to develop automation, that's why I wanted to ask if you know a solution to this issue.

I download the `XML` file or `cer` file, I get a `This type of file can harm your computer` pop up. I want to disable this pop up using selenium `ChromeDriver` and I want these types of files to be downloaded always. How can this be done?

My configuration:

1. Chrome version:80.0
2. Selenium version: 3.8.1
3. Chromedriver version: 2.42

I found this code, but cap object in `DesiredCapabilities` doesn't work with `ChromeDriver` anymore;

```
HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadFilepath);
chromePrefs.put("safebrowsing.enabled", "true"); 
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(cap); //this driver doesnt work anymore
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you add an example website

Comment: the website I am working is in a closed network so I cant give an example but I amtrying to download .cer or .XML file. Only in chromedriver running tests, security question is asked , without chromedriver test, in the website I can download  files without being asked about downloading question by manuel.

Comment: ANy website that creates similar issue like you are facing could help in giving correct answer

Comment: "This type of file can harm your computer. Do you want to keep ...cer anyway?" is the question is being asked while chromedriver executes test, but when ı download, it directly download. Is the any solutions for this problem I could not find anything.Thank you replying btw.

Comment: In your browser you could have disabled safe browsing where as when it launched from selenium it launch with safe browsing enabled. check with chrome://settings/security?search=safe

Answer (score 2):

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
prefs.put("safebrowsing.enabled", true);
prefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\prave\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe");
ChromeDriver driver=new ChromeDriver(options);
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait (driver, 20);

driver.get("http://www.landxmlproject.org/file-cabinet");
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[text()='MntnRoad.xml']//following::span[1]//a[text()='Download']"))).click();
```

Just use : setExperimentalOptions , `safebrowsing.enabled` and `("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);`

You can use:

```
 options.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);
```

if you want to accept insecure cert

Answer (score 0):

To hide the warning *`This type of file can harm your computer`*  and enable downloading of **xml** type of files using Chrome/ChromeDriver you need to:

- Add the preferences:

  - `download.default_directory`
  - `download.prompt_for_download`
  - `download.extensions_to_open`
  - `safebrowsing.enabled`
- As well as add the following arguments to whilelist:

  - `--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection`
  - `safebrowsing-disable-extension-blacklist`
- Code Block:

  ```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
  Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
  prefs.put("download.default_directory", "C:/Utility/Downloads/");
  prefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", false);
  prefs.put("download.extensions_to_open", "application/xml");
  prefs.put("safebrowsing.enabled", true);
  ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
  options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
  options.addArguments("start-maximized");
  options.addArguments("--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection");
  options.addArguments("safebrowsing-disable-extension-blacklist");
  WebDriver driver =  new ChromeDriver(options); 
  driver.get("http://www.website.com");
  ```

Answer (score 0):

To disable the "This type of file can harm your computer" pop-up while downloading XML or CER files, you can try setting the following Chrome options:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", 
                Map.of("download.default_directory", downloadFilepath, 
                       "download.prompt_for_download", false,
                       "safebrowsing.enabled", true));
options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
options.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
options.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
options.addArguments("--disable-infobars");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

This will automatically download XML or CER files to the specified directory and bypass the security warning.